# Can Microwaves ever need Libun?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, technology, kashering-kosherization

Very often microwaves have food splattered all over them. If the oven were to need to be Kashered would the spots that had food on them need Libun since they absorbed food directly (without a liquid medium)?

Comment: I don't think that is Rov Tashmisho. Rov Tashmisho is with Zeiah.

Comment: In many microwaves there is food stuck to the walls most of the time. I'm curious what that is considered.

Comment: Pretty sure the Star K just requires ha'agalah (read: put a cup of water inside and let the microwave run until the water spills out - sounds like somewhere between ha'agalah and libun to me).

Comment: @DonielF I don't understand. That's not somewhere between Hagalah and Libun. That has nothing to do with Libun. Anyway, does that address my point?

Comment: @Eliyahu They say to do that method after scrubbing the microwave clean. I'll have to dig out the article, but when I do, I'll post it as an answer, BN.

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page here. I know that's what is normally done. Scrubbing it clean is always necessary for Hagalah. It's not necessary for Libun.